# Show that $f$ is increasing without the first derivative test.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be the function defined as follows : $f(0)=1 / 2$ and for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$
by : $$ 
f(x)=\frac{\exp (x)-1-x}{x^{2}}$$

I could show that this function is increasing by studying the sign of the derivative, are there other ways to show this ?

Comment: You could use the Maclaurin series (i.e., Taylor series around $x = 0$) for $e^x$, but that obviously comes from using derivatives, so I don't think that really fits what you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnOmielan that's still nice to know

Comment: No, it can still be done with binomial expansion and geometric series. Check baby Rudin 3.30 and 3.31 for an idea.

Comment: @JohnOmielan using Mclaurin series I don't see how we can prove it for the negative reals, can you give me a hint ? I

Comment: @the_firehawk I, like Bhaswat, also misread $R^{*}$ to be $R^{+}$, so I don't know offhand how to prove it for negative reals using the Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 2):

$\exp(x)= \sum_{i=0}^\infty(x^i/i!))$, so your expression evaluates to $\sum_{i=0}^\infty(x^i/(i+2)!))$, each term of the summation is monotonic, so the sum is monotonic.

Comment: that's a very neat way, I like it.

Comment: this method would indeed show monotonicity, we can also immediately deduce that the function is increasing on the positive reals but unfortunately not the negative reals.

Comment: My bad! interpreted $R^*$ to be $R^+$

Comment: That is not true in general. For example $x=-1$ and $y=-2$, but $x+y<0$

Comment: @ yep I realized it quickly and removed the comment, sorry.